# How to escape character in .expect when doing ssh operations in pexpect

Tags: python, regex, pexpect

I am Learning pexpect and very new to it, I am trying to get the hostname of another machine by using pexpect module of python.

When I am calling **child.expect('root@.*:~\#')** it is throwing an error called
searcher: searcher_re:
0: re.compile(b'root@worker01:~#')

The expected string after successful(ssh) login is  **root@worker01:~#**

The code is below

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
  
import pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn('ssh shobhit@xxx.xx.xx.xx')
child.expect('shobhit@.*password:')
child.sendline('y@9')
print('Logged In')
child.expect('root@.*:~\\#')
child.sendline('hostname')
print(child.before)
print('Got Hostname')
child.expect('root@.*:~\#')
print(child.before)
child.sendline('exit')
print('logged Out')
```

I have tried escaping #, but I can't find that it is a regex pattern to be escaped. tried giving without \ too, but nothing seems to be working

Comment: The 'searcher' text is just the last line of the debug information. The first line will tell you what the error actually is. Please add the full text as it will show what the error is and what the cli presented. Also, using raw strings like r'root@.*:~#' ensures python doesn't mess with your escape characters and they go straight through to pexpect.

Answer (score 0):

https://pythex.org/ has a calculator and a cheat sheet. `#` doesn't need to be escaped.

I suspect it's not matching `root` because you're logging in as `shobhit`. Try a more general regex to make sure you're getting a prompt:

```
....
print('Logged In')
child.expect('@')
child.sendline('hostname')
...
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can try that pattern:

```
ssh.expect(r'root@\.\*:~\\\\#')
output=ssh.before.decode('utf-8')
```